# Couchbase shutdown in docker swarm

Tags: docker, couchbase, docker-swarm

Running couchbase in a docker swarm shots down. Following [this](https://blog.couchbase.com/docker-service-swarm-mode-couchbase-cluster/)

I do the following on/in docker swarm:

1.

```
docker network create -d overlay couchbase
```

2.

```
docker service create --name couchbase-master -p 8091:8091 --replicas 1 --network couchbase -e TYPE=MASTER arungupta/couchbase:swarm
```

I can see that it is down with:

```
docker service ps couchbase-master
```

Note: I can run nginx and other services. Do you know how to debug/ see the log from Couchbase(not just the log from docker service logs)

Comment: do you see an logs in container that suggest its exiting? To view logs you should do `docker ps -a` and this will show you exited containers that were attempted and then you can use `docker logs <containerid>`.

Comment: docker service ps <service name> just says shotsdown. Note that it is in docker swarm

Comment: Service is a swarm only command so of course i know this is docker swarm. But it does launch containers. So you should check using `docker ps -a` on each node and find where the container was started. Then you can use `docker cp <containerid>:/log/path/to/couchbase .` and get the logs out of that container to inspect

Comment: Right, thanks. Found the "Exited" container. And "docker cp <id>"  returns: Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d5aa9ebb80303a26411291a8eda2311e7320b84fc71b2975ff75449daaffd43e/log/path/to/couchbase: no such file or directory

Comment: My command was just an example you need to correct the path based where the couchbase logs go

Comment: Thanks, now I have the logs. One step closer :-)